# Sub directive triggers parent click-event in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, directive

i got the following structure:

```
<div directiveA>
    <a href="" directiveB>
</div>
```

Both directives got an onclick event. The problem is, that if a click on directiveB is performed, a click on directiveA is triggered as well.

How can i prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the directiveB on the click directive do this this

`ng-click=doSomething();$event.stopPropagation()`

There is an `$event` object available for all DOM events supported by angular.